# Hierarchical routing with plain Express.js

Tags: node.js, routes, url-routing

I’m implementing a RESTful API using Node and Express. When it comes to routing, currently it looks like this:

```
var cat = new CatModel();
var dog = new DogModel();

app.route('/cats').get(cat.index);
app.route('/cats/:id').get(cat.show).post(cat.new).put(cat.update);

app.route('/dogs').get(dog.index);
app.route('/dogs/:id').get(dog.show).post(dog.new).put(dog.update);
```

I don’t like this for two reasons:

1. Both cat and dog models are instantiated whether I need them or not.
2. I have to repeat /cats and /dogs for every path schema

I’d love to have something like this (not working, of course):

```
app.route('/cats', function(req, res)
{
    var cat = new CatModel();

    this.route('/').get(cat.index);
    this.route('/:id').get(cat.show).post(cat.new).put(cat.update);
});

app.route('/dogs', function(req, res)
{
    var dog = new DogModel();

    this.route('/').get(dog.index);
    this.route('/:id').get(dog.show).post(dog.new).put(dog.update);
});
```

Is there a clean way in modern Express without any further modules (like [express-namespace](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-namespace))? I could go for separate routers for each model and assigning them with `app.use('/cats', catRouter)`. However, what if I have more than one hierarchy level like `'/tools/hammers/:id'`? I would then have routers within routers within routers, which seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I would then have routers within routers within routers, which seems like overkill to me.

Perhaps, but that is the built-in method of prefixing -- to [`app.use()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) a [`Router()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router).

```
var cats = express.Router();
app.use('/cats', cats);

cats.route('/').get(cat.index);
cats.route('/:id').get(cat.show).post(cat.new).put(cat.update);

// ...
```

And, to have one `Router` [`.use()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.use) another to define multiple depths:

```
var tools = express.Router();
app.use('/tools', tools);

var hammers = express.Router();
tools.use('/hammers', hammers);

// effectively: '/tools/hammers/:id'
hammers.route('/:id').get(...);
```

---

Though, to be closer to your 2nd snippet, you can define a custom method:

```
var express = require('express');

express.application.prefix = express.Router.prefix = function (path, configure) {
    var router = express.Router();
    this.use(path, router);
    configure(router);
    return router;
};

var app = express();

app.prefix('/cats', function (cats) {
    cats.route('/').get(cat.index);
    cats.route('/:id').get(cat.show).post(cat.new).put(cat.update);
});

app.prefix('/dogs', ...);

app.prefix('/tools', function (tools) {
    tools.prefix('/hammers', function (hammers) {
        hammers.route('/:id').get(...);
    });
});
```

Comment: Top notch answer! Especially your second example pushed my JavaScript/Node skills a little further.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [new Router](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x) in Express 4. It sounds exactly what you're looking for.